# Create a recursive string function for adding a sequence

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've a challenging problem and so far I wasn't able to solve.

Within my xlst I have variable which contains a string.
I need to add the following sequence [eol] to this string.
On a fix position namely every 65 characters

I thought to use a function or template to recursive add this charackter.
The reason is that the string length can variate in length.

```
    <xsl:function name="funct:insert-eol" as="xs:string" >
    <xsl:param name="originalString" as="xs:string?"/>
    <xsl:variable name="length">
        <xsl:value-of select="string-length($originalString)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="start" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="eol" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:value-of select="65"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="newLines">
        <xsl:value-of select="$length idiv number('65')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $newLines">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($originalString, $start, $eol)" />
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:function>
```

The more I write code the more variables I need to introduce. This is still my lack on understanding.

For example we want every 5 chars an [eol]

### aaaaaaabbbbbbccccccccc

aaaaa[eol]aabbb[eol]bbbcc[eol]ccccc[eol]cc

---

Hope someone has a starting point for me..

Regards Dirk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rather straight-forward and short -- no recursion is necessary** (and can even be specified as a single XPath expression):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:param name="pLLength" select="5"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vText" select="string()"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="1 to string-length($vText) idiv $pLLength +1">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($vText, $pLLength*(position()-1)+1, $pLLength)"/>
    <xsl:if test=
    "not(position() eq last()
       or position() eq last() and string-length($vText) mod $pLLength)">[eol]</xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<t>aaaaaaabbbbbbccccccccc</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
aaaaa[eol]aabbb[eol]bbbcc[eol]ccccc[eol]cc
```

**When this XML document is processed:**

```
<t>aaaaaaabbbbbbcccccccccddd</t>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
aaaaa[eol]aabbb[eol]bbbcc[eol]ccccc[eol]ccddd[eol]
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre you always surprised me. I need to have a to check with my current solution. I like recursion but only if it's necessary.

Comment: @Dirk, You are welcome. Recursion isn't always efficient and in the general case recursive code tends to crash for a long sequence of items -- like having 1000 or more items.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat it as a grouping problem, using `for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:function name="mf:insert-eol" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="chunk-size" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:value-of>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="string-to-codepoints($input)" group-by="(position() - 1) idiv $chunk-size">
    <xsl:if test="position() gt 1"><xsl:sequence select="'eol'"/></xsl:if>
    <xsl:sequence select="codepoints-to-string(current-group())"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:value-of>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:insert-eol(., 5)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That stylesheet transforms

```
<root>
  <text>aaaaaaabbbbbbccccccccc</text>
</root>
```

into

```
<root>
  <text>aaaaaeolaabbbeolbbbcceolccccceolcc</text>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I liked the recursive solution, very need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsl:param name="TextToChange" select="'aaaaaaabbbbbbccccccccc'"/>
  <xsl:param name="RequiredLength" select="xs:integer(5)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="AddText"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="AddText">
    <xsl:param name="Text" select="$TextToChange"/>
    <xsl:param name="TextLength" select="string-length($TextToChange)"/>
    <xsl:param name="start" select="xs:integer(1)"/>
    <xsl:param name="end" select="$RequiredLength"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$TextLength gt $RequiredLength">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($Text,$start,$end)"/>
        <xsl:text>[eol]</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="AddText">
          <xsl:with-param name="Text" select="substring-after($Text, substring($Text,$start,$end))"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="TextLength"
            select="string-length(substring-after($Text, substring($Text,$start,$end)))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$Text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```